# как узнать реализацию метода Set.retainAll(), да и других методов тоже

Tags: java, intellij-idea

подскажите прописана ли где-то реализация данного метода? не понимаю почему иногда в Intellij IDE в справочной системе, или как она называется, есть реализация каких-то методов, а иногда просто сигнатура. в java doc просто описания без конкретного кода. Иногда очень интересно узнать как реализован тот или иной метод

Comment: Ctrl + B не работает?

Comment: работает но показывается только сигнатура. нет кода, т.е. того как реализован метод

Comment: Ну так вы в интерфейс проваливаетесь, походу.

Comment: да вы правы) так и есть) остается теперь понять где именно прописана реализация... я создаю new HashSet c типом Set... у HashSet такого метода нет.... и я в ступоре снова(

Comment: есть такой метод) посмотрите в ответе. а вообще нет же проблем найти класс `HashSet` и поковыряться в нем

Comment: я увидел щас в java doc методы, унаследованные от интерфейсов. они прописаны там немного ниже. но как будто в самом классе HashSet нет реализации этого метода. будто он реализован в другом каком месте. меня бы просто ткнуть в эту реализацию а дальше я сам смогу сориентироваться.

Comment: https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/master/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/AbstractCollection.java, ctrl+f и ищите retainAll

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`как узнать реализацию метода Set.retainAll()`

`retainAll()` реализован в абстрактном классе `AbstractCollection`, и далее наследуется в `AbstractSet`, а `HashSet` в свою очередь наследует `AbstractSet`. Наследование позволяет не переопределяя метод родительского класса работать с ним как со своим.

---

`почему иногда в Intellij IDE в справочной системе, или как она называется, есть реализация каких-то методов, а иногда просто сигнатура`

Потому что вы когда вы видете только метод с сигнатурой - в частых случаях вы просто открываете интерфейс. Иногда можете попасться на нативный метод.

Чтобы увидеть реализацию, опять же, по вашему вопросу того же `Set`, то вам нужно провалиться не в интерфейс `Set` а в одну из его реализаций, например в `HashSet`.

Так вы провалитесь в реализацию методов `Set` в `HashSet`

```
HashSet<Object> set = new HashSet<>();
set.add(new Object());
```

А так в интерфейс `Set`

```
Set<Object> set = new HashSet<>();
set.add(new Object());
```

Или если вы попали в интерфейс, там IDE уже может подсказать где реализованы методы

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: спасибо большое) я дошел до этого шага но не вижу в списке HashSet... ( причем если я создаю с типом HashSet то меня кидает вообще в Collection

Comment: однозначно, что-то делаете не так.

Comment: какой метод вы ищете?

Comment: однозначно)) пишу HashSet<Object> set = new HashSet<>(); затем вызываю set.retainAll() через cntrl+B перехожу в сигнатуру метода в интерфейсе Collection. Если написать Set<Object> set1 = new HashSet<>(); и так же вызывать set1.retainAll() то попадаю в сигнатуру метода в интерфейсе Set... такие дела. но там только сигнатуры, там нет кода. а где он тогда вдуплить не могу

Comment: `retainAll` реализован в абстрактном классе `AbstractCollection`, а далее наследуется в `AbstractSet`, а `HashSet` в свою очередь наследует `AbstractSet`. Наследование позволяет не переопределяя метод родительского класса работать с ним как со своим.

Comment: всё понял спасибо большое за помощь)) щас буду осмысливать произошедшее. немного смущает что в java doc не прописан код. только в Intellij можно его увидеть получается...

Comment: возможно вы пропустили в джава доках

Comment: не знаю... я в доках кроме описания больше ничего не видел. в том же классе AbstractCollection онли описание метода retainAll()